# Ignore Regex escape sequences C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm having trouble telling Regex to ignore any escape sequences.

Here is some example code:

```
string input = "?";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, "?"))
      {
         ...
      }
```

But when it is executed, it throws the following error:
parsing "?" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.

I just want the "?" to be handled as a string.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I have also tried:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, "\?"))
                {
...
                }
```

Which tells me that is is not recognized as a valid escape sequence.

I've also tried:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, "\x3f"))
                {
...
                }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.NET provides a function that does any escaping for you automatically. Whenever you have some kind of input string, that you want to match *literally* (just the characters that are there), but you know you use a regex search, then run them through this method:

```
string pattern = Regex.Escape(literalString);
```

This will take care of any characters that might be meta-characters for regular expressions.

[MSDN on `Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `?` for the *regex* engine, as `?` has a specific meaning as a quantifier in regular expressions:

```
\?
```

You will also want to use [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) so `\` doesn't have special meaning as a C# string escape sequence - these two are equivalent - `@"\?"` and `"\\?"`.

So:

```
string input = "?";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"\?"))
{
     ...
}
```

In general, the backslash `\` is the escape sequence *within* regular expressions.

Comment: I've tried that, but it is not recognized as an escape sequence. I've also tried replacing the "?" with "\x3f" with no avail. And what about other strings like: "+"?

Comment: @user1869353 - Yes, you need to remember that you are working with _two_ languages - there is the C# string escape and the regex escape.

Comment: Use two slashes and not one

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape ? as 
`\\?`

in the regular expression and not in the text.

Check out this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in Escape method.

```
Regex.Escape("/")
```

See also [MSDN RegEx.Escape()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)